# Constant timer doesn't work for OS process sampler when I use 20 mins instead of 10 mins

Tags: jmeter

My structure is like this:

```
thread group1
 -- simple controler1
   -- http request

thread group1
 -- simple controler1
   -- OS Process Sampler
   -- Constant timer (Thread Delay 10 minutes)   --->> this works fine
```

However, when I try to add more time to my constant timer, say 20 mins, it stopped working, and excepted right after.

All I want to achieve is to wait for a certain time, say 30 mins, for the first http request to finish.

Can anyone out there please shed some light?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute samplers from second thread group after all samplers from first thread group select your [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) and set option `Run Thread Group consecutively (i.e. one at a time)` to the `true`.

[image]

Check more [tips for optimizing JMeter test plans](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/10/8-tips-for-optimizing-jmeter-test-plans/)

Comment: Thank you very much, and i figured to use the thread group delay to achieve the same goal. thank you much for this tips too.